# Syncing data with Core Data

Tags: objective-c, macos, performance, cocoa, core-data

I'm writing data from iTunes to Core Data.

Now, the first sync ever takes about 10 seconds,
However, updating the data takes about 30 seconds.
My computer has an SSD, so it's most likely to be even slower on a HDD.

What I'm doing is, I'm getting an array of songs, and I have to make a fetch for each song to check if it's already in Core Data, and if not, I have to insert it.

The only way to know if a song is already existent is to check the `persistentID`.
It's basically a persistent unique id for identification.

I can see if the song is already added by checking

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"persistentID == %@", song.persistentID];
```

Not a very smart idea.

What advice can you give me for speeding this up?

Comment: Is that literally an individual call into Core Data per song to check for existence?

Comment: @Tommy I'm doing a fetch for each song. I could probably fetch one time and then check if the song is in the array, but I doubt that this would be much faster

Comment: it should be substantially faster, especially if you set `returnsObjectsAsFaults` to `NO`. Otherwise every fetch and then the first access of a store-backed field on any fetched object is a trip to the persistent store, which beyond the SQLite costs is written to be thread safe so you have a whole bunch of locking mechanisms to jump through. I'm not confident enough about the specifics of iTunes and the persistentID to elevate this into a proper answer though.

Comment: @Tommy Ok, the problem is that I only have the `persistentID`, I'd have to do a predicate filter again to find out if the song is in the array

Comment: @Tommy I tried to clarify the `persistentID` in my question.

Comment: But couldn't you collect all the persistentIDs you're going to check against in one pass, without touching Core Data, do a single query for every song in the store matching any of those persistent IDs, totalling one Core Data access, then perform in-data searches within that return set, without touching Core Data again? `NSSet`, `NSArray`, etc can all apply predicates in memory so your code wouldn't get that much more ugly. Or am I still not understanding?

Comment: @Tommy The problem is that `[someArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]` is pretty slow. I just had an idea, however. I could get all the songs from core data, and just get an array of a keyPath => `allPersistentIDs = [allSongsFromForCoreDataArray valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.persistenID"]`. The I can do `[allPersistentIDs containsObject:@( persistentIdAsFloat )]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get the ids of all the songs you want to compare against. Then you can get the new songs with a single trip to the persistent store.

Get the IDs,

```
NSArray *allIDs = [existingSongs valueForKeyPath:@"persistentID"];
```

and then do a fetch with a predicate like this.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"persistentID NOT IN %@", allIDs];
```

Answer (score 1):

The first sync is always going to be short because it's not going to do any fetch requests.

Core data likes:
Batch Requests
Small batches

For batch requests, Mundi has answered that perfectly.  This smaller set will be only the ones you need to update.

The next part refers to smaller batches.  You can speed up the updating tremendously if you break it down with multi-threading.  Since you're saving and I don't know enough about the data set, check out [multi threaded core data tutorial on cimg](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/).